# How to determine percent stake in a token?

Tags: tokens, smart-contract-wallets

I'm working on an experiment that distributes some number of tokenB to people who own tokenA.  the distribution of tokenB is dependent on what percent of tokenA is owned.

is it even possible to determine what percent of tokenA is owned by an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tokens follows the [ERC20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard use functions `totalSupply` and `balanceOf` to calculate the relative percentage.

```
function percentage(address token, address user, uint256 scale) public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 totalSupply = IERC20(token).totalSuply();
    uint256 balance = IERC20(token).balanceOf(user);

    return balance * scale / totalSupply;
}
```

The `scale` parameter is needed because solidity only supports integers and any percentage will be less than 1 and then rounded to zero.